# Why my tax calculation (SA302) doesn't show my dividends through a service company?

Tags: income-tax, mortgage, united-kingdom, dividends, limited-liability-company

I've submitted my tax return (Self Assessment) to HMRC for the recent year and I've enter my total of the dividends (from my Limited company as contractor) into *Service companies* box as below:

[image: SA302/SA100 - Service companies - Dividends]

as per [guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/354204/sa150.pdf):

> You provided your services through a service company if:
>
> - you performed services (intellectual, manual or a mixture of both) for a client (or clients)

However when HMRC sent my tax calculation (SA302), my total income shows `£0.00` as shown below:

[image: SA302 - HMRC - Tax Calculation]

which doesn't make any sense.

However it shows fine when I had previously dividends entered in different section (see: [SA100 form](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/438649/sa100.pdf)), into this one:

[image: SA302/SA100 - Dividends from UK companies]

Why my dividends through a service company doesn't add up into my total income?

Secondly, in that situation, how would I potentially apply for the mortgage if my income is `£0` on my tax calculation?